# Angular 2 interpolation converts number to string

Tags: angular, type-conversion, string-interpolation

I have the following component where within onClick event I am trying to increment/decrement the value of its count field. However, when I do this it convert the count field to string. I understand that interpolation convert everything to string but should not it convert string to correct type because I work with field that? Am I missing something here?

```
import {Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'like',
  template: `<i class="glyphicon glyphicon-heart" [class.liked]="isLiked" (click)="onClick()"></i><span>{{count}}</span>`,
  styleUrls: ['./like.component.css']
})
export class LikeComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() isLiked: boolean;

  @Input() count: number;

  @Output() change = new EventEmitter();

  constructor() { }

  onClick() {
    console.log(typeof this.count); // <--- string

    this.isLiked = !this.isLiked;

    this.count = Number(this.count) + (this.isLiked ? 1 : -1);

    this.change.emit({value: this.isLiked});
  }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Comment: Where does the input come from? Do you have a `<like count="{{count}}"></like>`?

Comment: Yes, it looks exactly like this: <like count="10"></like>

Comment: Does `<like [count]="10"></like>` work?

Comment: It does. I see now how it works. Thanks!

Comment: Is it a good practice to use brackets for binding everywhere or only for non-string fields?

Comment: Use square brackets when you want to bind an expression; omit them when you want to provide a literal string value.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<like count="10"></like>
```

is like

```
<like [count]="'10'"></like>
```

so do

```
<like [count]="10"></like>
```